# How do you make a function that returns a promise work properly inside of a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

Since a function that returns a promise is asynchronous, how would you use it inside of a forEach loop? The forEach loop will almost always finish before the data being fetched or manipulated by the promise returning function can complete its data manipulation.

Here is an example of some code where I am having this problem.

```
        var todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency = [];

        listOfItemIdsAndSaleFrequency.forEach((item) => {

            Product.findById(item.itemId).then((foundItem) => {

                var fullItemData = foundItem.toJSON();

                fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;

                todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency.push(fullItemData);

            });

        });

        return res.status(200).json(todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency);
```

The array called todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency is sent back to the client empty. findById is a mongoose function which returns a promise, so it doesn't fully populate the array by the time the response is sent back to the client.

Comment: _"The forEach loop will almost always finish before the data being fetched or manipulated by the promise returning function can complete its data manipulation."_ What is expected result? Can you include `js` tried at Question?

Comment: Each one will still execute, maybe return at different times, but they're all still separate calls.

Comment: You don't. You use a `map` loop, as `forEach` is only for functions that don't return anything. You then can use `Promise.all` on the resulting array of promises.

Comment: I added specific code to show what I'm dealing with.

Comment: Define `res`, `listOfItemIdsAndSaleFrequency`, `Product`

Comment: res is response as this snippet of code comes from a node.js route. listOfItemIdsandSaleFrequency is an array of objects with two keys "itemId" and "occurences" and Product is just an plan object fetched from a mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a `forEach` loop, as that works only with functions that don't return anything. If they return something, or a promise for it, you'll have to use a `map` loop. You then can use `Promise.all` on the result, the array of promises:

```
Promise.all(listOfItemIdsAndSaleFrequency.map(item => 
    Product.findById(item.itemId).then(foundItem => {
       var fullItemData = foundItem.toJSON();
       fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;
       return fullItemData;
    })
)).then(todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency => {
    res.status(200).json(todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency);
})
```

Comment: Where do I push fullItemData onto todaysTopItemsBySaleFrequency?

Comment: You don't need to. `Promise.all(…)` already fulfills with an array of the results from all the promises. Just `return` it, there's no need to `push`.

Comment: [It waits for all the promises in an array and returns a promise for an array of results](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using AngularJS. The idea is to build up a promise array in your foreach loop and then use the $q service to invoke them ($q.all(promiseArray))

```
                    var promiseArray = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {

                        var request = $http({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: url,
                        });
                        promiseArray.push(request);
                    }
                    $q.all(promiseArray).then(function (data) {
                        //when all prmises are finished
                    }, function (err) {

                        console.log(err);
                    });
```

Comment: I added code to make my question more specific to my situation.